# MySql export - Oracle's flashback_time equivalent for MySql

Tags: mysql, export

As someone that is new to MySql... In the context of doing a database export,,, Is there an equivalent to Oracle's flashback_time parameter for MySql?

The closest thing I found is the "lock-tables" command, but not quite the same thing, since it blocks data from being changed when it is used, thus making an app for the database not usable by users. Whereas the " Oracle flashback_time" parameter allows the database to be usable while still producing an export whose data is consistent to a single point in time

Comment: Man that would be nice if this exists, because I ended up having to build a change log for each table to pass the old and new values, who did it, when, what column and value, and all that, so in theory i could search by a date and get what the data use to be around that time frame in case a user accidently or maliciously changed or deleted it, it could be recovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature of MySQL that allows you to export data as of an arbitrary timestamp in the past.

You can dump the *current* state of data without locking in the following way:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB, because then **it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.**

(emphasis mine)

InnoDB tables are the default, so it's likely that all your table are InnoDB already.

You might also like to evaluate [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup), which is a free, open source hot backup tool for MySQL.